# How can i protect the app from "CLEAR ALL" action

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I want to protect (or) lock my app from clear all recent apps list. Here i mentioned what I'm asking. Please find the screenshot below. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer. Add ***android:lockTaskMode="always"*** in your activity.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.your.app.activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:lockTaskMode="always">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent application from closing by user.
You can use the Services to execute your process provided that the user has allowed the application to auto start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MahdiZarei. I'm asking how to lock the task programmatically. Because above showing app, default to having that lock. But i can't find how they did? so that i asked here. If you want to check that code please find here https://github.com/mdasari823/Android-QoE-App/tree/master/testRunningServicesBackgroundRelaunched